# Two dialogs followed with many choice in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I've created a script that allows me to create folders and organize files for my work.

But i wish have a first dialog box asking me if I want to create a "web project" or a "graphic project". Then, according to my choice a second dialog box who give me several choices.

**Explanations :**

If I choose a "Web Project" in the first dialog box. This will open a second dialog box with several new choices.

Could you help me with this please ?

This is my first dialog box that i've created : (it works perfect)

```
set theName to (choose from list {¬
    "Create Web Project", ¬
    "Create Graphic Project"})

if theName is false then

    display dialog "Cancelled." buttons {"Exit"} default button {"Exit"} with icon note

else

    if first item of theName = "Create Web Project" then
        set userResponse to (choose from list {¬
            "Create Responsive Website Project", ¬
            "Create Desktop Website Project", ¬
            "Create Mobile Website Project", ¬
            "Create Tablet Website Project"})

        tell application "Finder"
            set resPath to (path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources:Scripts:Web:" & userResponse & ".scpt"
            set the_script to load script alias resPath
        end tell

        run script the_script


    else if first item of theName = "Create Graphic Project" then
        set userResponse to (choose from list {¬
            "Create Basic Design Project", ¬
            "Create Print Design Project", ¬
            "Create ADS Banner Design Project"})

        tell application "Finder"
            set resPath to (path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources:Scripts:Graphic:" & userResponse & ".scpt"
            set the_script to load script alias resPath
        end tell

        run script the_script

    end if  

end if
```

**EDITED: i've edited my code inspiring by your code. It works but i don't have the good alerts box !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set theName to (choose from list {¬
    "Create Web Project", ¬
    "Create Graphic Project"})

if first item of theName = "Create Web Project" then
    set userResponse to choose from list {"A", "B"}
else if first item of theName = "Create Graphic Project" then
    set userResponse to choose from list {"C", "D"}
end if
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help ! I've edited my code, could you see if it's good and help me with Alerts Box please ;-) 

Lot of Thanks